# Is it possible to block specific outbound hostnames for SSH SOCKS users?

Tags: linux, security, ssh, ssh-tunnel, socks

Is it possible to block connections to specific hostnames for users accessing the web via an SSH SOCKS proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iptables has the `owner` module which allows you to specify rules by the uid/gid. I guess that should work for you. So, something like this should work:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d some.host.name -m owner --uid someuser -j DROP
```